# How to handle modules in multiple webservers behind a load balancer?

Tags: magento2, loadbalancing

This is my setup:

- DB Server
- NFS Server for shared media files
- Load Balancer
- Web Server 1
- Web Server 2

What is the best way to handle installing modules?  The only thing I can think of is going into each Web Server and installing the modules.

I haven't found any really good resources on the topic as a whole.  I have heard I should also share pub/static for combined css/js, but didn't know if anyone had any good resources for the whole "Magento Community Load Balanced Setup" topic.

Comment: you install on one server, then sync to others or using glusterfs share.

Answer (score 0):

One war to solve is to automatize deployment. A first step is to use deployer.
DeployerPlus for Magento2 is awesome and you can deploy to multiple hosts per stage like this:

host('abc1.net/production', 'abc2.net/production